# Probability of a two-state continuous Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

Consider a continuous-time Markov process ($\epsilon_t$) which takes two values ($\epsilon_t=0$ or $\epsilon_t=1$). Let $p_0$ denote the probability of switching from state 1 to 0 and let $p_1$ denote the likelihood of transitioning from state 0 to 1.

Can we calculate conditional probabilities like
\begin{align}
f(x|y)=P(\epsilon_t=x | \epsilon_0=y)
\end{align}
where $x,y\in\{0,1\}$?

Comment: It is simple here, having 2 one-bit values as input is equivalent of having 2-bit value 0..3 as input,and you have common Markov process.

Comment: @user184868 Could you please provide a little more information? I can't quite follow how to translate your explanation to my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: In a CTMC it doesn't really make sense to specify things with transition probabilities. You need to specify transition rates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the calculation in the discrete time case is explained on page 3 of [1], and it works similarly in the continuous time case.

If $u_t=P(\epsilon_t=0 | \epsilon_0=0)$ then
$$u_t'=p_0(1-u_t)-p_1u_t \,.$$ Thus $z_t=u_t-c$ satisfies
$$z_t'=p_0(1-z_t-c)-p_1(z_t+c)=-(p_0+p_1)z_t+p_0-(p_0+p_1)c \,.$$
This suggests choosing $c=p_0/(p_0+p_1)$ so the equation for $z_t$ becomes
$z_t'=-(p_0+p_1)z_t$. We have arrived at the most standard differential equation. By the product rule, $f(t)=e^{(p_0+p_1)t} z_t$ satisfies
$f'(t)=0$ for all $t$, so $f(t)=f(0)=1-c$. we conclude that
$$u_t=\frac{p_0}{p_0+p_1}+\frac{p_1}{p_0+p_1} e^{-(p_0+p_1)t} \,.$$

[1]https://yuvalperes.com/markov-chains-and-mixing-times-2/
https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/mcmt2e.pdf

Comment: To be clear, your $p_0$ and $p_1$ in this answer are actually rates, not probabilities.

Comment: If the Markov chain has iid exponential (1) waiting times between jumps, then the transition probabilities become rates

Comment: Strictly speaking that's not how that works for a few different reasons (units, for one...rates have units and probabilities don't) but I get your point.